# onMeasure is called 1,500+ times

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-viewpager, onmeasure

I've recently noticed a significant performance issue with my app. I essentially have the following layout...
[image]

**DESCRIPTION**

In short, there is a `ViewPager` that holds 3 `RelativeLayout`s as pages. Inside each page there a number of `TextView`s. I recently noticed a lot of lag when I type into the `EditText` that has a `TextWatcher` on it to perform a quick SQL query for autocompleting. My HTC One M8 stutters and lags as I input text, but I know it isn't the querying that is slow because I measured queries taking only about 7 ms.

I used method profiling, Systrace, and plain old `Log` debugging and concluded that each time I typed a character in the `EditText` about **1,700** calls to `onMeasure` were being made on the `TextView`s within `RelativeLayout` A, B, and C. Cumulatively, there are only about 15 independent `TextView`s across the pages. I noticed that **each `onMeasure` is being called hundreds of times instead of just once or twice** like it usually might.

**QUESTION**

I don't know why typing in the `EditText` in page B would cause other `TextView`s in pages A and C to also get "re-measured". More importantly, does anyone have insights on why `onMeasure` is being called so often? And, does anyone know of a solution to significantly reduce the number of calls to `onMeasure`?

**DETAILS**

This may help: I was actually able to cut the the number of `onMeasure` calls to about 900, by removing `RelativeLayout` 2 which could suggest the propagation of `onMeasure` calls starts outside of the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Please post your layout XML file.

Comment: Is your EditText set to wrap_content? If so, it's probably re-measuring on each text change to ensure the text still fits.

Comment: I did initially think that was the problem, so I made the width `match_parent` as well as attempting to hard code a width, but still no luck.

Comment: @cygery I'll post the XML file as soon as I can, I'm away from my code base right now but I thought the diagram would be sufficient. As far as I can tell, I don't see anything special about my layout that could cause this problem because there was a point in my development where I wasn't having this problem and I basically used the same layout.

Comment: OK, I'm asking because the issue could be caused by some values for layout_width etc. as @kcoppock hinted. Don't you use a version control system or have a backup of a working version?

Comment: Hmm, yes I use git for my project and there is easily a version I can revert back to that isn't having this problem; but I'd lose quite a bit of other work. I can go more in depth and tell you that I did a tedious `git diff` and looked line-by-line for what I could have changed wrong. Nothing significant, as far as I could tell, looked like it'd warrant such strange behavior... Even if it was a `wrap_content` issue, could it cause this "cascading" effect where `onMeasure` gets called so often on the same `View`s? I'm all ears, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I don't have enough information to identify the specific problem, I can tell you, in general, what is happening:

A call to a root view's `measure` causes a call to each sub-view's `measure` and so on, down the tree.

Suppose that the view called "current view", after asking each of its sub views to measure themselves, decides that there is not enough space for all of the children.  It will ask them each to measure themselves again, suggesting a max size.  Suppose, then, that the view called "Relative Layout B" changes its size, radically, based on the specified max.  Because the change is so big, "current view" must asks each child one more time.  This loop could easily require a couple more iterations to resolve.

When "current view" decides on its size, it reports back to "View Pager".  Suppose that "View Pager" does not have enough space for its three views, and has to ask them to re-measure, with a max.  We are now up to at least 20 calls to the TextView's `onMeasure`.  If each of the other views above ViewPager iterates a few times, pretty soon you start seeing big numbers.

The best solution, as you've already pointed out, is to reduce the depth of that tree.  Alternatively, you might use layout managers that have much simpler measurement algorithms (FrameLayout, LinearLayout)

1500 is a lot though.  One of those views is doing something weird.  You should be able to identify it very simply, using the TreeView tool in the DDMS suite.  In eclipse it is called "TreeView".  In Studio, click the Android icon and switch to the Hierarchy View perspective.  You can also run it from the command line, from the SDK tools directory.

**Added:**
If you connect Hierarchy Viewer to your app while it is running, you will see the entire view tree in one of its panes.  Each node in the tree will have three colored gumdrops towards the bottom.  The first gumdrop represents the measurement phase.  If the gumdrop is green, the measurement phase for that view is fast.  If it is yellow, that node is in the top 50 percentile of nodes in the layout.  If it is red, it is the slowest in the layout.

You should be able to follow a trail of yellow right to the offending view.

Comment: Thank you! This is certainly insightful. I've really only used Hierarchy View once and I don't know everything you can do with it. Is it possible to perform any debugging within it? Like following all the `onMeasure` calls.

Comment: Can't debug with it.  Do that with eclipse or studio.  HV will tell you where to look, though.

Comment: I've tediously gone through my entire set of layouts and wasn't able to pinpoint an exact offending view. Instead, I worked on simply reducing my layout tree by optimizing some layout choices and removing some entirely. The number of onMeasure calls has been reduced down to around 150 which seems "normal" consider that `Views` are often asked to remeasure 4-8 times at a time. Thanks for the thorough explanation!